# How to set Radio button to navigate user based on activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-radiobutton

I am new to android programming. I want to set radio button on top of every activity to navigate user.
So that it will help to user can understand which activity they are in.

please anyone guide me.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: is all tabs are fragment or there is multiple activities?

Comment: Use Fragments, for Delivery, confirmation, payment and Finish task. And show this process on the main activity and display those fragments according to your flow on main activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following layout in each of activity and then change colors of views according to activity

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_circle_pink_24dp"/>
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#EC2A47"
    />
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_circle_pink_24dp"/>
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#ADACAC"
    />
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_circle_grey_24dp"/>
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#ADACAC"
    />
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_circle_grey_24dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#EC2A47"
        android:text="Delivery"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="start"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#EC2A47"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Confirmation"


        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ADACAC"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Payment"

        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ADACAC"

        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:text="Finish"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

ic_circle_pink_24dp.xml

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:tint="#F24459"
android:viewportHeight="24.0" android:viewportWidth="24.0"
android:width="24dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<path android:fillColor="#FF000000" android:pathData="M12,2C6.48,2 2,6.48 2,12s4.48,10 10,10 10,-4.48 10,-10S17.52,2 12,2z"/>
```

ic_circle_grey_24dp.xml

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:tint="#ADACAC"
android:viewportHeight="24.0" android:viewportWidth="24.0"
android:width="24dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<path android:fillColor="#FF000000" android:pathData="M12,2C6.48,2 2,6.48 2,12s4.48,10 10,10 10,-4.48 10,-10S17.52,2 12,2z"/>
```

Output as follows:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @Ashi Agarwal :) this is that I expected same